# Is a lesbian ending for Sophie ruled out?

Tags: character, how-i-met-your-mother, how-i-met-your-father

I remember in *How I Met Your Mother* (HIMYM) s1 that it was already established in [the matchmaker episode](https://how-i-met-your-mother.fandom.com/wiki/Matchmaker) (S01E07) with [Camryn Manheim (Ellenor Frutt from *The Practice*!)](https://how-i-met-your-mother.fandom.com/wiki/Ellen_Pierce) that Ted is not gay / bisexual. In short, Ted is exclusively heterosexual.

Transcript:

(see 1:16 [here](https://youtu.be/Cr4ON-YIQXA?t=76))

> Ellen: How do you think I feel? I have a 100% success rate. It's my
> hook. I could probably find somebody for you if you were gay.
>
> Ted: Well, I'm not.
>
> Ellen: A little bi maybe?
>
> Ted: No. You're messing with me, right?
>
> Ellen: Come see for yourself.

**Question**: Is there anything similar for Sophie in HIMYF s1? (Or if there's something HIMYF s2, then feel free to answer once s2 starts airing.)

**Context**: I have this strange feeling that Ian vs Jesse is somehow a red herring for Sophie x Valentina or Ellen.

Like a similar trick to what was done in HIMYM, the 2008 movie *Definitely, Maybe* or *The Legend of Korra* (spin-off of *Avatar The Last Airbender*). Sophie could have a biological child with either Ian or Jesse and even end up marrying 1 of them but I don't see what's stopping Sophie to ultimately ask out Valentin or Ellen after a divorce with or the death of the husband if any.

So I wanna see if there's anything similar like Sophie went to a matchmaking place and said specifically 'I'm not bisexual'.

**Edit based on [Darth Locke](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/56522/darth-locke)'s suggestion in comments**:

I am looking for dialogue or clarification from the Eps, writers, or cast

Comment: Some people are voting to close as "Opinion-based" without explaining why. I'm guessing they've misunderstood the question and think you're asking for speculation and theories, when actually you're simply asking if there has been any dialogue or other events that establish Sophie's sexuality?

Comment: @BCLC You might want to clarify that you are looking for dialogue and/or clarification from the Eps, writers, or cast...As the previous comment states, some are taking this as an opinion-based answer when there could be a legit answer from legit sources...

Comment: @DarthLocke thanks. i already edited after 2 close votes. I think the 3rd close vote is just joining in. After all, we don't see the times that the close votes were casted right?

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 thanks. i already edited after 2 close votes. I think the 3rd close vote is just joining in. After all, we don't see the times that the close votes were casted right?

Comment: @BCLC no, we do not see when close votes were casted. SE likes to encourage users to put others down at the first sign of imperfection. To prove this look at this line in the how to ask a question article: "DON'T ask questions where every answer is equally valid." Which means they promote black-and-white vision and refuse to see the grey.

Comment: @Xenon errr ok.... what now? btw equal in that sense means like opinion instead of could be either yes or no for equally good reasons? something like 'the same' vs 'equal' ? eg [Is Hogwarts the only magical school in the UK?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252227/is-hogwarts-the-only-magical-school-in-the-uk)

Comment: @BCLC I was just making that statement. I wasn't actually expecting a response. Sorry if I was weird.

Comment: @Xenon You weren't weird at all. Or if you were weird, then you were weird in a good way. Thanks a lot for the feedback. Actually I wanted to see if you were being sarcastic or something. So like you agree it would be helpful to show a timestamp for close votes and that a lack of timestamp seems to be part of that 'SE likes to encourage' etc?

Comment: I cast the initial Close Vote, because of several reasons: you are referring to things by acronyms, expecting users to get what you're talking about; comparing two situations without sufficient apparent reason; invoking (seemingly) completely unrelated titles; and ultimately asking if someone ever explicitly stated what their sexual orientation is or is not, the advantage of knowing which I don't see anywhere.

Comment: @Joachim Without this matchmaker episode what's to rule out that Ted ends up with Gary Blauman?

Comment: @BCLC I still think you haven't sufficiently clarified that you want "legit" information. The word "anything" is too broad and invites loose opinion-based theories/comments over tight speculation and/or facts from proper sources. As Joachim explained, you need to write everything out.

Comment: @DarthLocke S02E03 update. see answer.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

According to S02E03 it is not ruled out.

> [image]

Comment: Don't hide the entire answer behind a spoiler block.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the closest thing I've found so far:

Later in S01E01, Sophie says 'I've been on 87 Tinder dates this year.'

[image]

And 'I don't do, like, sexy stuff with all the guys.'

[image]

However:

1. 'Guy' is sometimes gender-neutral.
2. It could be that Sophie means e didn't do sexy stuff *for whomever were male among the 87 dates*.
3. Korra probably dated only males before Asami.